# error:Reverse for 'centreupdate' with keyword arguments '{'pk': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['NewApp/centreupdate/(?P<slug>[-\\w\\d]+)']

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

I wanted to use a field value instead of primary key in my url, I looked up on the internet and found some code to do so.I want to use slug in the centreupdate url, but I am not even able to access the centrelist url.What am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

models.py

```
class Centre(models.Model):
name= models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, unique=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length =250)
phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{9,15}$',
                             message="Phone number must be entered in the format: '+999999999'. Up to 10 digits allowed.")
contact = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
phone = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=10, blank=True)  # validators should be a list
slug = AutoSlugField(unique_with='id', populate_from='name')


def __str__(self):
    return self.name

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("index")
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^createcentre/$', views.centre.as_view(), name='centreinfo'),
url(r'^centrelist/$', views.CentreListView.as_view(), name='centrelist'),
url(r'^centreupdate/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)',views.CentreUpdateView.as_view(),name='centreupdate'),
url(r'^centredelete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.CentreDeleteView,name='centredelete'),
```

Comment: You need to update where you are *calling* that URL, with the `{% url %}` tag or the `reverse()` or `redirect()` functions.

Comment: I updated the url like this : {% url 'NewApp:centreupdate' slug=c.slug %}( c is the loop variable for model in template) but now i am getting : Reverse for 'centreupdate' with keyword arguments '{'slug': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['NewApp/centreupdate/(?P<slug>[-\\w\\d]+)'] this error. Please Help.

Comment: The slug field in one of your models is blank.

Comment: I have used slug for only one model.

Comment: Yes. And one or more of the instances of that model has an empty slug. Or `c` is not what you think it is.

Comment: I had to delete the migrations and remove all the data from database. Now it is working fine. I think slug was not able to take the values for the data created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `pk` but in url you declare `slug` so that it aspect a slug but not found.
Change here

```
url(r'^centreupdate/(?P<pk>[-\w\d]+)',views.CentreUpdateView.as_view(),name='centreupdate'),
```

Comment: WHat is the use then? It is still displaying primary key because of this url.

Comment: INstead of this `url(r'^centreupdate/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)',views.CentreUpdateView.as_view(),name='centreupdate'),`